# How can i know if system bars are visible?

Tags: android

I try to know on each devices (tablet and phone with or without physical button) if system bars are visible (status bar, navigation bar and system/combined bar).

How i can do that ???

François

edit: android:minSdkVersion=11 in my app

Comment: Since you do not need this information to have a successful Android app, what are you *really* trying to achieve? There may be a better solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I need to know the height of my page in portrait mode in dp. It seems to be simple but sometimes the height includes the STATUS bar, the NAVIGATION bar or the COMBINED bar. I work on an app for handwriting and in that kind of application, i need to know the real height of my "page" on EACH devices if I want good recognition results

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know the height of my page in portrait mode in dp.

Then measure the height of the `View` that represents your "page".

Comment: sorry but it don't work for me because if i am in landscape, i want the real height of the portrait mode. In fact the size of my "page" is the size of the view "in portrait". In that case, I can't take the width because the size of status bar changed on some devices for example...

Comment: @FrançoisBOURLIEUX: You will have to come up with a different design, as what you want is not reliable. For example, various Samsung devices offer S-Apps, allowing two apps to reside side-by-side, which may not work with your calculations. Similarly, some devices, like the Kindle series, do not have a fixed bar, but one that comes and goes. Other devices, or even core Android itself, may do the same thing in the future. You need to create a design that *only concerns itself with its own views*, not what is happening with space outside of its available drawing area.

Comment: I understand your point of view. It seems that the only good way to do that could be to use a fixed size for the "page" and use a zoom to keep compatibility with all devices...